# Game Center? Xcode

Tags: xcode, center, game-center, gamekit

I have been working ver hard on Game center. I have tested so many codes I've lost count.
I would love to know how to automatically submit score as well
here are some codes i have used but i am not sure if this will help

```
-(IBAction)showleaderboard:(id)sender{
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController   alloc]init];
if (leaderboardController !=NULL) {
    leaderboardController.category = self.currentLeaderboard;
    leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
}

}
-(void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[viewController release];

}


-(IBAction)showAchivementLeaderboard:(id)sender{
GKAchievementViewController *achivements = [[GKAchievementViewController alloc]init];
if (achivements !=NULL) {
    achivements.achievementDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:achivements animated:YES];
}
}
-(void)achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)viewController{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[viewController release];

}

self.currentLeaderboard= kEasyLeaderboardID;
if ([gameCenterManager isGameCenterAvailible]) {
   self.gameCenterManager= [[[GameCenterManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.gameCenterManager setDelegate:self];
    [self.gameCenterManager authenticateLocalUser];
}else{

    UIAlertView *openURLAlert = [[ UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game Center turned    off" message:@"You are not connected to game center." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [openURLAlert show];
    [openURLAlert release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To report a score you need to use GKScore as follows;

```
GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:self.gameCategory.leaderboardString];
scoreReporter.value = score;

[scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {

        [[KYTGlobals instance] storeScore:score forCategory:self.gameCategory.leaderboardString];

        }
 }];
```

The above code allocates and inits a GKScore object using the identifier that you have already set up on game center for the category that you want to report a score for.  You update the value for the score and then use reportScoreWithCompletionHandler making sure to test for error so that you can archive the score and report it later.